# GWT ListBox() Java MySql

Tags: mysql, gwt, listboxitems

I have selected records from mySql table and and have inserted each record into an array list. I am trying to insert each value into a position the drop down list box.

I am stumped...any suggestion on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you cant access the mysql database from the Client side in GWT. you need to amke a call to the server and which will make a call and return the results to client(may be in the form of a class object(serializable)) and then you can add it to dropdown list.

For using the dropdown list the following code might help

```
public void demo()
{
    VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
    panel.addStyleName("demo-panel-padded");
    panel.setSize("200px", "120px");
    panel.add(getListBox(false));
    panel.add(getListBox(true));
    RootPanel.get("demo").add(panel);
}
ListBox getListBox(boolean dropdown)
{
    ListBox widget = new ListBox();
    widget.addStyleName("demo-ListBox");
    widget.addItem("One");
    widget.addItem("Two");
    widget.addItem("Three");
    widget.addItem("Four");
    widget.addItem("Five");
    if(!dropdown)widget.setVisibleItemCount(3);
    return widget;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I was able to access the information from the db by my server I was just not passing the infromation back correctly to the client. sorry for the confusion